# Why do wirenuts overheat & melt?

Tags: electrical, wiring, heat

[image]

A normal blue wirenut is shown in the bottom left corner.  The large red wire powers a heat pump evaporator and its fan.

The arrow points to a melted blue wirenut.   What cause wire nuts overheat?

Comment: That should never happen.  Is it possible that heat from an external source did that and not the current in the wire?

Comment: I can read `AWM` as a marking on the wire, that's Appliance Wiring Material. Can you get us a clear picture of the rest of the labeling on the insulation? Since there's speculation that it could have been aluminum wire, the wire labeling would answer that question.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely an indication of a poorly-made connection, which is a *particular* issue with [aluminum interior wiring](https://www.wirechiefelectric.com/aluminum-wiring-in-homes-answers-to-common-questions).

Though aluminum is a very good conductor and light-weight, it forms an insulating aluminum oxide coating on the surface, which gradually reduces the area of contact, funneling all the current through a small surface. In addition, aluminum is soft, and easily broken, so connections cannot be sufficiently tightened, and its expansion coefficient does not match that of copper or the steel coil in the wire nut, leading to gradual loosening.

If it's *not* aluminum wiring, overheating due to excessive current, improper tightening, or use in a hot location, such as stove or furnace, might have caused that damage. Since a heat-pump should never get very hot, look to a poorly-made connection.

Another, though rare, cause might be a nearby lightning strike (not a direct hit), which can induce very high voltages and currents. Is that heat pump outdoors?

Comment: That's not considered a suitable connector for aluminum wiring, in the US, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Poor connections that have high resistance or arcs. Generally from not tightening properly or using the wrong wirenut for the size & number of wires.

A polaris-type connector may be more foolproof, if torqued properly.

Comment: I think you are indicating a poor connection cause arcing, which emits significant heat?

Comment: @gatorback, correct, which of course can melt or ignite anything, not just wire nuts.

Comment: Def have to agree with Ecnerwal, poor connections create heat.  I always twist the wires together first, ensuring they have a solid connection, then put on the wire nut to keep it that way.  Lazy electricians and manufactures just stick the wires in the nut, twist it on and call it a day.   Not good. Not reliable.

Comment: Or a merely poor connection has high resistance, which leads to heating, which can lead to arcing which makes much more heat once it starts. What are the size, number and conductor material of the wires in this connection?

Comment: Aluminum wire connections with wire nuts require anti-oxidant paste to be long lasting.  Burndy Penetrox is recommended by Jesse Aronstein, electrical engineer.

Comment: is this a high current circuit, perhaps the electrical resistance backup heat?

Comment: The air handler has been buttoned up: the red wire in the photograph supplies power to the air handler / evaporator.  Not sure what he gauge of the wire was, but if memory serves, it was copper.